# Compress HTML - Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, compression

I have dropdown-Lists which have a lot of elements (>1000). When I select one of those elements the dropdown has to be rebuild because the selection of one element can cause others to disappear. I solve this in code behind (asp.net). Showing and hiding that dropdown usually is done in several milliseconds.

But when I select an element the div has to be rebuild which takes up to 20 seconds which is no surprise as that div contains about 300KB of Data which have to be sent to the client. The DIV looks like this:

```
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_SubstancesList" class="substancesListWrapper">
<ul>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','3268');">(2-Propyloxy)ethyl acetate</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2415');">[(2-Propenyloxy)methyl] oxirane</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2837');">1-(2-Pyridyl) piperazine</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2239');">1,1,1,2-Tetrachloro-2,2-difluoroethane</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2880');">1,1,1,2-Tetrafluoroethane</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2110');">1,1,1-Trichloroethane</a></li>
(etc.)
```

Now I wonder if there is a way to compress that div-String and decompress it client-side by jQuery or something like that to reduce traffic. Does that work and if yes: What percentage of bytes do I usually safe?

This all happens in a SharePoint-Site (which should not make any difference hopefully)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might improve several things.
One would be to move all your JavaScript links into one.
This would save you 85 characters per row.

```
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','3268');">(2-Propyloxy)ethyl acetate</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href="JavaScript:__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances','2415');">[(2-Propenyloxy)methyl] oxirane</a></li>
```

Could become this

```
<li class='elementSingle'><a href='#3268'>(2-Propyloxy)ethyl acetate</a></li>
<li class='elementSingle'><a href='#2415'>[(2-Propenyloxy)methyl] oxirane</a></li>
...
```

And one jquery click handler:

```
jQuery("li.elementSingle a").click(function(){
  __doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances', this.href.replace('#',''));
});
```

---

Another point would be to remove class='elementSingle' and add a id to your ul for css/js.
This would save 22 characters per row.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try that. The "class" - thing does not work, because in reality there are more than one class (some lines are different). I will reduce that to "eS". That will help a bit, I think

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery already, just remove the anchors completely and provide id attributes for the list item elements.

The use a jQuery selector that reads out the id.

HTML would look kinda like this...

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_SubstancesList" class="substancesListWrapper">
<ul>
  <li class='elementSingle' id="ct100-3268">(2-Propyloxy)ethyl acetate</li>
  <li class='elementSingle' id="ct100-2415">[(2-Propenyloxy)methyl] oxirane</li>
  etc...
```

The jQuery could be something like this...

```
$(function() {
  $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_SubstancesList .elementSingle')
  .click(function() {
    var number = $(this).attr('id').match(/-(\d+)$/)[1];
    __doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctlProductSelector_pnlSubstances', number);
  });
});
```

(disclaimer; above is untested, but should give you a decent indication. Post a jsfiddle example first if you want a tested example).

Alternatively, think about using AJAX to load the list after loading the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just as an addition to the last sentance: The DIV is already created in an UpdatePanel. So it is Ajaxified

Comment: If it's already loaded from Ajax, you could render the HTML at client-side, keep a list in memory and omit all the id's and classes you don't need for CSS. You could even load/render parts of the HTML as needed.